# Protractor: testing with data

Tags: testing, protractor

Any tips or best practices for writing tests involving data?  My app has a search bar that searches the database for matching text.  For example:

Search 'Joe', will return all people with firstname = 'Joe', lastname = 'Joe', or has 'Joe' in their email address.

I can think of 2 potential ways to test this:

1) Search for 'Joe', and check the data returned.  Every row returned should have 'Joe' in firstname, lastname or email.  Issue with this is if a row should be returned, but isn't, the test won't pick this up.

2) Load test data, run search and check results.  In this case, I know exactly how many rows should be returned.  This effectively means I need to load test data before running each test (and delete it after...in case my code is broken and it writes bad data, it wont screw me up next time i run test).

Any thoughts?  Is there a 3rd option?

Comment: Take a look at [Possibility for parameterized/data driven test with protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/620) and [Include test data file in protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/978).

Comment: could you send your code.